# Recursively find files using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io

I have a class ReverseWriter. Constructor takes 3 arguments: path to directory in which I should search for Java files, path and name for new directory in which modified files will be stored and thread pool that is created in Main class. My application should recursively find files (and process each subdirrectory and file in separate thread) in given directory and it's **subdirrectories**. Here's the part of Main class code:

```
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ReverseWriter reverseWriter = new ReverseWriter(dirToSearch, dirToStorePathName, pool);
        pool.submit(reverseWriter);

        System.out.println("All files reversed!");

        pool.shutdown();
```

And here is the **run** method of ReverseWriter class:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {

        File[] files = dirToSearch.listFiles();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(files));
        if (files != null) {
            for (File f : files) {
                System.out.println(f.getName());
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    ReverseWriter reverseWriter = new ReverseWriter(f, dirToStorePathName, pool);
                    pool.submit(reverseWriter);
                } else {
                    reverseWrite(f);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**reverseWrite** is the method that modifies file. For testing my application I created a folder with 5 Java files, 1 txt file, 2 folders that contain Java files. The problem is that my application modifies and writes 4 modified files and doesn't modify files that are in subdirrectories. While debugging, I found that when in method **run** the subdirrectory is found then the application stops proccessing subdirrectories and files stored in them. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can somebody give me a tip how to fix this?

Comment: What does "stops processing" mean?

Comment: One problem could be that you shut down your executor service in the main thread which means won't be able to add new tasks within the run method after the shutdown statement is executed.

Comment: @tgdavies The program stops looking for files in subdirrectories and doesn't modify them as well. Also it doesn't modify files in initial directory that are alphabetically after found subdirrectory.

Comment: @JANO I've commented shutdown statement in Main class. Everything works correctly now, but now the running time of the program increases very much and the program seems to freeze, although after a while it finishes its work. Do I need to shutdown pool in different way than before?

Comment: It could be that the program needs more time now as it is actually doing the work it should do. I would check if the time is spent during the file modification.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You may want to try using `ExecutorService pool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();`, which doesn’t have to be shut down.

Comment: Hitting the same drive in multiple threads with `File.listFiles` will be slow. You may find single thread `Files.find` or `Files.walkFileTree` is not only quicker but much simpler to implement.